# Selenium Capture Screenshot and save to sql

Tags: java, sql, selenium, screenshot

I need to know if there's a way for selenium rc to capture a screenshot, but instead of saving it as a .png to a specific directory , I want it to be saved in a MySQL database. Is there a simple way like a selenium method that returns an image or a file ? I'm using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with captureScreenshotToString and save the result in the database.

public java.lang.String captureScreenshotToString()

Capture a PNG screenshot. It then returns the file as a base 64 encoded string.

Specified by:
        captureScreenshotToString in interface Selenium

Returns:
        The base 64 encoded string of the screen shot (PNG file)

Comment: Yeah I thought there would be something else than 'toString'..but Thanks